# Mongosh connection error: MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate’s altnames

Tags: database, mongodb, database-connection, mongo-shell

I’m learning MongoDB and set up an Atlas account. I’m trying to connect to my database using mongosh, allowed all IPs, set up my user and password credentials but I’m getting an error:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-00.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mongodb.net, DNS:mongodb.net
```

Upon checking my logs, this is what shows:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:27.465Z"},"s":"I","c":"MONGOSH","id":1000000000,"ctx":"log","msg":"Starting log","attr":{"execPath":"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.6.0/bin/node","envInfo":{"EDITOR":null,"NODE_OPTIONS":null,"TERM":"xterm-256color"},"version":"1.7.1","distributionKind":"packaged","buildArch":"x64","buildPlatform":"linux","buildTarget":"unknown","buildTime":"2023-02-13T19:19:00.135Z","gitVersion":"1bf0d7775443ac1849cc2597465d54eca867acea","nodeVersion":"v19.6.0","opensslVersion":"1.1.1s","sharedOpenssl":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:27.469Z"},"s":"I","c":"MONGOSH","id":1000000005,"ctx":"config","msg":"User updated"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:27.470Z"},"s":"I","c":"MONGOSH","id":1000000048,"ctx":"config","msg":"Loading global configuration file","attr":{"filename":"/etc/mongosh.conf","found":false}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:27.475Z"},"s":"E","c":"DEVTOOLS-CONNECT","id":1000000041,"ctx":"mongosh-deps","msg":"Missing optional dependency","attr":{"name":"mongodb-client-encryption","error":"Cannot find module 'mongodb-client-encryption'\nRequire stack:\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/node_modules/@mongodb-js/devtools-connect/lib/connect.js\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/node_modules/@mongodb-js/devtools-connect/lib/index.js\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/node_modules/@mongosh/service-provider-server/lib/cli-service-provider.js\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/node_modules/@mongosh/service-provider-server/lib/index.js\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/lib/cli-repl.js\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/lib/index.js\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/lib/run.js\n- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongosh/1.7.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/@mongosh/cli-repl/bin/mongosh.js"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:27.517Z"},"s":"I","c":"DEVTOOLS-CONNECT","id":1000000039,"ctx":"mongosh-connect","msg":"Resolving SRV record succeeded","attr":{"from":"mongodb+srv://<credentials>@cluster0.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?appName=mongosh+1.7.1","to":"mongodb://<credentials>@ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-00.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net,ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-01.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net,ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-02.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?appName=mongosh+1.7.1&authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-142s5d-shard-0&tls=true","resolutionDetails":[{"query":"SRV","hostname":"_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net","error":null,"wasNativelyLookedUp":true},{"query":"TXT","hostname":"cluster0.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net","error":null,"wasNativelyLookedUp":true}]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:27.530Z"},"s":"I","c":"DEVTOOLS-CONNECT","id":1000000042,"ctx":"mongosh-connect","msg":"Initiating connection attempt","attr":{"uri":"mongodb://<credentials>@ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-00.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net,ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-01.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net,ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-02.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?appName=mongosh+1.7.1&authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-142s5d-shard-0&tls=true","driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"4.14.0"},"devtoolsConnectVersion":"1.4.4","host":"ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-00.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net:27017,ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-01.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net:27017,ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-02.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net:27017"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:27.867Z"},"s":"W","c":"DEVTOOLS-CONNECT","id":1000000034,"ctx":"mongosh-connect","msg":"Server heartbeat failure","attr":{"connectionId":"ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-02.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net:27017","failure":"","isFailFast":false,"isKnownServer":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:28.053Z"},"s":"W","c":"DEVTOOLS-CONNECT","id":1000000034,"ctx":"mongosh-connect","msg":"Server heartbeat failure","attr":{"connectionId":"ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-01.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net:27017","failure":"Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-01.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mongodb.net, DNS:mongodb.net","isFailFast":false,"isKnownServer":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-15T10:21:28.200Z"},"s":"W","c":"DEVTOOLS-CONNECT","id":1000000034,"ctx":"mongosh-connect","msg":"Server heartbeat failure","attr":{"connectionId":"ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-00.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net:27017","failure":"Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: ac-kiiemsq-shard-00-00.cbhjwlv.mongodb.net. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mongodb.net, DNS:mongodb.net","isFailFast":false,"isKnownServer":true}}
```

I’ve tried connecting through Mongodb Compass and the connection is successful. I'm using a Mac with mongoDB and Mongosh installed through brew, all updated to the latest version.

Comment: How do you connect? Usually MongoDB should provide valid certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downgrade your version of mongosh to 1.6.2, you will be able to connect.

```
brew uninstall mongodb-community
brew uninstall mongosh
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/4519776bc4563548dcd8c8639ac7e073b107c381/Formula/mongosh.rb
brew install ./mongosh.rb
```

Comment: 1.6.2 is the latest version of `mongosh`, how can you **down**grade to this version?

Comment: The latest version is [1.7.1](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mongosh)

Comment: Interesting, the Mongo Shell [Release Notes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/changelog/) goes up to version 1.6.2

Comment: @JasonKlein your solution worked! Thank you so much, I've spent the whole day yesterday trying to troubleshoot this. How'd you know it was a specific error for the latest version of mongosh? Tried searching everywhere for the same issue and couldn't find any resource on it.

Comment: I did not find any error report either, it could be a serious one. Maybe the just forgot to put the Crypt library into the bundle.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit for now I'm sticking to 1.6.2, hoping they fix it eventually!